# I want to change value of count , what's wrong in this code? ( React Function Component )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({firstName: "AA",lastName: "BB",address: [{name: "AA",count: 0}]});
const plus = () => {setUser([ ...user.address, user.address[0].count + 1 ]);}
return (
<h1>{user.address[0].count}
)
```

I tried to wrap up setUser to object

Comment: you initialize `user` as an object, and then set it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Spread the object and inner array separately when updating the state:

```js
setUser({ ...user, address : [ {...user.address[0], count : user.address[0].count + 1}, 
                              ...user.address.slice(1) ] });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not properly updating the state. If spread operations are confusing for you, you can use [`immer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer).

Install `immer` using one of the following.

```bash
npm i immer
pnpm add immer
yarn add immer
```

Then you can use `immer` as follows.

```
import produce from "immer";

...
...

setUser(produce(state => {
  user.address[0].count += 1; 
}));

...
...
```